# Unshift from object list without using delete?

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, object

If I can access an object from an object using `list[value][index]`, how can I delete or unshift that object from `list` without using `delete`? (since that isn't possible in an object list)

My object looks like this:

```
var list = {
    'test1': [
        {
            example1: 'hello1'
        },
        {
            example2: 'world1'
        }
    ]
    'test2': [
        {
            example1: 'hello2'
        },
        {
            example2: 'world2'
        }
    ]
};
```

After deleting an object, I want it to look like this:

```
var list = {
    'test1': [
        {
            example1: 'hello1'
        }
    ]
    'test2': [
        {
            example1: 'hello2'
        },
        {
            example2: 'world2'
        }
    ]
};
```

When I use delete, it looks like this:

```
var list = {
    'test1': [
        {
            example1: 'hello1'
        },
        null
    ]
    'test2': [
        {
            example1: 'hello2'
        },
        {
            example2: 'world2'
        }
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the object from `list` by setting the value of `list[key]` to `undefined`. This won't remove the key, however - you'd need `delete` to do that:

```
list['test1'] = undefined; // list is now { test1: undefined, test2: [ ... ]}
delete list['test1']; // list is now { test2: [ ... ] }
```

Is there a particular reason you don't want to use `delete`? It won't make a difference if you're just checking `list['test1']` for truthiness (e.g. `if (list['test1']) ...`), but if you want to iterate through `list` using `for (var key in list)` or something like that, `delete` is a better option.

**EDIT:** Ok, it looks like your actual question is "How can I remove a value from an array?", since that's what you're doing - the fact that your array is within an object, or contains objects rather than other values, is irrelevant. To do this, use the [splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method:

```
list.test1.splice(1,1); // list.test1 has been modified in-place
```

Comment: I fixed my main post, I outlined the wrong part I want to delete.

Answer (score 0):

(Rewritten for corrected question.)

You can write:

```
list[value].splice(index, 1);
```

to delete `list[value][index]` and thereby shorten the array by one. (The above "replaces" `1` element, starting at position `index`, with no elements; see [`splice` in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) for general documentation on the method.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using splice:

http://jsfiddle.net/hellslam/SeW3d/